# Pandas - Return the closest datetime from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with unique datetime stamps for each row. I would like to create a column in the 1st dataframe that contains the row number of the closest datetime in the 2nd dataframe. I know that with Pandas I can add a calculated column based on another column in the dataframe with one line of code:

```
df['calculated_column'] = df["sample column"]**2
```

Is there a way to do something similar for this lookup, or should I write a function to compare them line by line? My data is small enough that a line-by-line function would be manageable, but I'm looking for the correct/efficient way to do this.

I've tried numerous solutions. My latest attempt was to use the datetimes as indeces and the code below, but .get_loc won't accept a column in this manner.

```
df1["nearest_barometer_row"] = df2["datetime"].index.get_loc(df1["datetime"], method='nearest')
```

Comment: Looks like a case of `merge_asof`. You should include sample data and expected output.

Comment: Thanks Quang, I appreciate it - that worked like a charm. This is the working code:

    newdf = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='datetime', direction='nearest')